# Yii - How to Show Two Controllers in One Page

Tags: php, yii

I'm working on a project using the [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) php framework and I would like to show two controllers in the same, single create page.

For example, I want to show `question/create` forms and `answer/create` forms in one page then create it.

How can I do that?

Comment: okay solved by ourselves

Comment: Perhaps you could share your solution for others?